# Estimating a logit directly with ordinary least squares

Tags: regression, logistic, least-squares, data-transformation, odds-ratio

I've read that the coefficients on the logit regressions are equivalent to that of estimating the model:

$log(p/(1-p))$ = $\beta$$_o$+$\beta$$_1$X+$\eta$

If i wanted to transform my data to run this via ols, how do I do that? given that the dependent variable only takes on 0 or 1, how do I make the log odds ratio?

Comment: Because you cannot observe the values of $p,$ you cannot even get started with this approach.

Comment: ok so just to clarify- p is only estimated by estimating the logit function itself? so what i said above is just theoretically true, or true in the 'population'?

Comment: It's not even true in the population, because the values of $p$ are *model constructs.*  They can never be directly observed.

Comment: so if we hypothetically had the whole population, and fitted the logit model, are the betas the only 'true' parameters that would be found? why wouldnt that give us p, as Pr(y=1|x) is defined by the distribution?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely this form of model would exactly reproduce actual frequencies in any finite population (unless the population were artificially constructed for that purpose).  What, then, could the term "true parameter" possibly even mean??

Comment: So I am taking this model as estimating 'true' parameters of a population, i.e. estimating the beta's. my understanding was when setting up this MLE, we are assuming the data is being generated in a certain way, from a certain parametric class of distributions, and then finding a consistent estimator of the true population parameters.  so then with the logit specification, isnt p a function of these parameters? which is why I am confused about the p being a model construct vs a population concept.

Comment: It depends on whether by "population" you mean a set of objects to be sampled or a data-generating *process* or something in between.  Regardless, my original observation stands: $p$ is not something that can be observed or measured in any sample, so it's impossible even to get started with OLS.  To address your second comment, once you fit the betas, then the logit of $p$ is determined by them, and therefore so is $p.$